# iostat: avoid displaying loop devices information

Tags: loop-device, iostat

Given the annoying feature of `snap`'s `loop` devices, my `iostat` output in an `Ubuntu 18.04.02` is kind of like this

Is there a way to filter out `loop` devices other than `| grep -v loop` ?

```
$ iostat -xm
Linux 4.15.0-47-generic (pkara-pc01)    04/22/2019  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          19.85    0.03    5.64    2.18    0.00   72.30

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
loop0            0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    7.00    0.00   0.00     2.88     0.00   0.50   0.00
loop1            0.06    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    1.25    0.00   0.00     1.80     0.00   0.09   0.00
loop2            0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    7.47    0.00   0.00     6.57     0.00   1.06   0.00
loop3            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    2.40    0.00   0.00     2.50     0.00   0.00   0.00
loop4            0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    8.54    0.00   0.00     2.44     0.00   1.54   0.00
loop5            0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   10.29    0.00   0.00     2.86     0.00   0.76   0.00
loop6            0.05    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    1.55    0.00   0.00     1.89     0.00   0.17   0.00
loop7            0.06    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    1.39    0.00   0.00     1.75     0.00   0.24   0.00
sda              0.07    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   5.32   9.09    9.29   41.60   0.00    12.47     3.20   9.51   0.07
sdb             23.40  103.81      0.40     38.12     8.47    10.16  26.59   8.91    8.48    6.17   0.84    17.49   376.07   0.94  11.93
dm-0            31.96  113.83      0.40     38.08     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   12.17   10.89   1.63    12.74   342.57   0.82  12.00
dm-1            31.91  113.30      0.40     38.08     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   12.19   10.95   1.63    12.74   344.17   0.83  12.04
dm-2             0.02    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.51    0.00   0.00    19.90     0.00   0.41   0.00
dm-3             0.05    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    9.82   58.91   0.00    10.21     2.91  10.02   0.05
dm-4             0.03    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   14.23   64.80   0.00    14.69     3.20  14.35   0.05
loop8            0.02    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   10.54    0.00   0.00     9.13     0.00   2.67   0.01
loop9            0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   11.83    0.00   0.00     2.66     0.00   1.79   0.00
loop10           0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   28.96    0.00   0.00    20.96     0.00   3.20   0.00
loop11           0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   31.20    0.00   0.00    20.80     0.00   4.80   0.00
loop12           0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   18.56    0.00   0.00     9.28     0.00   1.56   0.00
loop13           0.02    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   11.77    0.00   0.00     9.36     0.00   2.12   0.00
loop14           0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   13.65    0.00   0.00     9.76     0.00   0.71   0.00
loop15           0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   30.40    0.00   0.00    20.96     0.00   4.08   0.00
loop16           0.04    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    3.85    0.00   0.00     5.22     0.00   0.49   0.00
loop17           0.03    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    5.23    0.00   0.00     2.48     0.00   1.00   0.00
loop18           0.03    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    4.66    0.00   0.00     2.50     0.00   0.70   0.00
loop19           0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   14.86    0.00   0.00     6.27     0.00   3.29   0.00
loop20           0.02    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   12.48    0.00   0.00     9.15     0.00   1.65   0.00
loop21           0.02    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    8.66    0.00   0.00     9.83     0.00   1.29   0.00
loop22           0.04    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    5.10    0.00   0.00     5.09     0.00   0.70   0.00
loop23           0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   16.32    0.00   0.00     3.05     0.00   1.16   0.00
loop24           0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   20.60    0.00   0.00     2.50     0.00   4.20   0.00
loop25           0.01    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00   16.30    0.00   0.00     2.44     0.00   2.37   0.00
loop26           0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     1.60     0.00   0.00   0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to exclude `loop` devices and display the rest, but including particular devices explicitly may help you, i.e.

`S_COLORS=always iostat -x -p nvme0n1 -p sda -p sdb -p dm-4`

Answer (score -1):

[edited]

Try

`iostat -xm -p {device name}`   # To display only specific device.

You can use sed instead grep,

```
iostat -xm | sed '/^loop/d'
```

If am not wrong,

More easy and best way is to pipe and filter. There is no specific way to exclude devices in 'iostat' command.